# Sign out from google in Android App Using API 8.3.0

Tags: android

By following method I am signing out from google integration in my app

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                               new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResult(Status status) {
                                       AndyConstants.loginorout = false;
                                       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);
                                   }
                               });
```

I am signing out successfully by this method but it is redirecting me to the RegisterActivity where my google integration button is present. I want to redirect to the HomeActivity which I have coded in above method but not working.

Comment: have you tried the signOut method rather than revoking access -- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: yes, before revoke I tried signout but same problem occurs

Comment: try using (finish();) and see what that does

Comment: android studio isn't allowing me to use finish(); (cannot resolve method)